# Enums for Redux actions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, enums

I've read a lot of opinion pieces recently expressing discontent with TypeScript's `enum`. Specifically, I have been told that the following would be bad practice for Redux actions:

```
export enum TODOS {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  REMOVE: 'REMOVE',
}
```

and instead to prefer string literals:

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';
export const REMOVE_TODO = 'REMOVE_TODO';
```

Is this better practice, and if so, why? In my naive opinion, the benefit to having `enums` would be a lack of collision, and first-class namespacing (e.g., two similarly acting services, say, two database services, could export `CREATE_TABLE` actions, without needing to elongate the name with the namespace to prevent collisions)

I can't find the link to the blog post, but the basic tenets were:

- Assigning of any numeric value to an enum:

```
enum Direction {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}

const strangeWay = 27 as Direction
```

Of course, doesn't apply to string enums

- "Runtime implications", of which I cannot remember the argument given. [Here's a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/9r1gzi/ts_enums_and_how_they_feel_odd_to_me_in_a_js/e8dbf4r/), which states the same, but doesn't give any reasoning as to what the runtime implications are, just that there are more to consider than strings

**EDIT**: Note that I'm not looking for opinions. I'm looking for the implications of choosing such a pattern

Comment: IMHO, this is not necessarily a bad practice, rather than an opinion. Your approach using enums seems to be a workaround to get more "safety" / "type-safety". Therefore I'd suggest, you check out the: `typesafe-actions` package.

Comment: I had run into issues, but can't recall what they were. I think it had something to do with how string enums don't get reverse maps. It was a very localized problem.

Comment: I use enums for redux actions and win a lot of type safety. Don't understand why one should label that 'bad practice'. (strong pro-enum opinion: https://christianlydemann.com/how-to-design-redux-apps-for-scalability/)

Comment: @Andreas_D I'm not looking so much for opinions - I believe this is an opinion, which is the problem! I'm more interested in the real implications that might have caused somebody to have that opinion. I agree about the strongly-typed argument.

Comment: @NickBull But how should we know that? Ask the person with that opinion and ask for his justification - or show a link, if it was posted on the web.

Comment: @Andreas_D I'm not following what you mean. You should know that from the edit in the question at the bottom. I don't think the author is the only person who would have knowledge of the implications of choosing enums or strings as representations for actions, so I'm not sure why I'd only ask them. This is a programming Q&A site, and that was a blog post - I think it's more appropriate I ask questions here, and not expect the author to answer my questions. Moreover, it's not the question I'm asking, as I've previously stated. I'm asking for any implications of the choice

Comment: @NickBull I think, I understand exactly, what you mean. You read and heard something (somewhere) and want us to think about possible problems with that pattern. Why don't you present their arguments and ask if that is true or reasonable? That would be easier for us and probably attract some to answer. If the authors of the articles that express discontent have strong arguments: share them.

Comment: @Andreas_D I am very sorry! I thought I'd included the link at the bottom. Yesterday was a bad day for me :)

Comment: @Andreas_D I've updated the post, apologies again

Answer (score 1):

> In my naive opinion, the benefit to having enums would be a lack of collision, and first-class namespacing (e.g., two similarly acting services, say, two database services, could export CREATE_TABLE actions, without needing to elongate the name with the namespace to prevent collisions)

This is why it's a bad idea. There is no collision / namespacing effect in the compiled JavaScript.

```js
export enum Example {
    foo ='foo',
    bar ='bar'
}

export enum Example2 {
    foo = 'foo',
    bar = 'bar'
}

console.log(Example.foo === Example2.foo)
```

Compiles into:

```js
export var Example;
(function (Example) {
    Example["foo"] = "foo";
    Example["bar"] = "bar";
})(Example || (Example = {}));
export var Example2;
(function (Example2) {
    Example2["foo"] = "foo";
    Example2["bar"] = "bar";
})(Example2 || (Example2 = {}));
console.log(Example.foo === Example2.foo);
```

In the compiled JavaScript, the two enum values will be identical. They resolve into simple objects with plain string values. So two different enums both using `CREATE_TABLE` would both result in identical action names of `'CREATE_TABLE'` as a string.

The TypeScript compiler complains that this expression will always result in `false`, but that's not true. So in this way, you introduce potential bugs which are invisible to the TypeScript compiler. Better stick to using `const` strings for action names.